# How can I get the full precision of a Float80 in Swift?

Tags: swift

Whenever I try to get the string representation of a Float80 I can't get over the first 20 digits in the decimal part.

```
let fract: Float80 = Float80(exactly: Float80(1) / Float80(i))!

let stringRep = fract.description
```

I also tried PI

```
print(Float80.pi.debugDescription)
```

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: Why not use `NSDecimalNumber`?  It can hold up to 38 digits.  Is that not sufficient for your needs?

Comment: I want the full 80 decimal precision.

Comment: Try `.debugDescription`

Comment: I did...doesn't work.

Comment: `Float80.ulpOfOne` is approx 1e-19, so the precision of that type is not more than 20 decimal digits.

Comment: @GhislainLeblanc You misunderstood. The `80` in the name `Float80` describes the size of the datatype: It's 80 bits. That does **not** mean it have 80 decimal digits of precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A precision of `Float80` Type is the following:

```
Float80.exponentBitCount        /*  15  */
Float80.significandBitCount     /*  63  */
```

Also, the first bit in this structure is used for sign.

[image]

But! Apple documentation [says](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html):

> **`Double`** has a precision of **at least** `15 decimal digits`, whereas the precision of **`Float`** can be **as little** as `6 decimal digits`. The appropriate floating-point type to use depends on the nature and range of values you need to work with in your code. In situations where either type would be appropriate, Double is preferred.

So the focus must be on the words **`at least`** 15 decimal digits. It's not promised to give you a greater precision in a result. But all calculations are made in 80-bit bit depth.

Hope this helps.